# Fixed parent, position it's child right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a top bar for my webpage thats seperated into two sections. However, I'm having difficulty getting my divs positioned. It would appear the wrap collapses with these styles set. Howe can I avoid this.

I have somthing like this,

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Css is as follows;

```
#wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#ff0;
}
#one {
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #f00;
}
#two {
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

I want it to display on page something like this...

---

### |One             | (wrap underneath) |           Two|

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The wrap "collapses" because none of the element has any height.

Comment: You would think adding content would define height, but that fails also...

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
#wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
#one {
  height: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
#two {
  height: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y3z9udos/1/)

Comment: Flexbox? Never heard of it. Is it widley supported?

Answer (score 1):

you can use flexbox

```css
#wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#ff0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#one {
     height:50px;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #f00;
}
#two {
     height:50px;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```